# MaterializeCss: SideNav not working properly after update

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I recently updated the css/js files of the [Materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) design in my project from v0.97.5 to v0.97.8.

I thought it wouldn't make much of a difference but my SideNav is not working right anymore. When I click on the menu, it does slide out but the dark overlay is on the entire screen and I cannot click anything. This is what it looks like:

[image]

It looks like the 'sidenav-overlay' div with the opacity is above the sideNav. Also, I cannot click on any menu inside this sideNav.

The implementation of this is basically similar to what is mentioned in the documentation. I'm not sure what changed over here.

EDIT1: 
My code -

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper light-blue lighten-1">
      <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav hide-on-med-and-down print-hidden">
        <li><a href="#!">Upload<i class="material-icons right">cloud_upload</i></a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="div-title">Admin</li>

        <li><a href="/admin/users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/roles">Roles</a></li>
      </ul>

      <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">view_headline</i></a>

      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">LOGO</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: i think changing/increasing `z-index` of your sidenav class element would fix this

Comment: @MJN I was thinking along the same lines, but I just messed around with the position of sideNav and it is working fine now.  I just had to take the `sideNav` div outside the `navbar-fixed` div.

Comment: I guess I posted the question too early. Thanks for looking into this though :)

Comment: @AyrtonSenna, can you post the code?

Comment: Just posted the code.

Comment: Is there a reason this question is being downvoted? should I change something?

Answer (score 2):

What fixed this was that my `side-nav` ul list was inside the `navbar-fixed` div. This wasn't an issue in the previous version but for some reason, this broke in the current 0.97.8 version.

Just moving the `side-nav` outside the navbar section fixed this for me. Hopefully this helps someone else in the same situation.